# Calculating mode in R

Tags: r, count, statistics, max, summarize

I have a data frame in R and I want to calculate mode for a column in it, I have tried to use combination of different commands but I am getting errors.
I have used these codes

```
july_data%>%
   group_by(weekday)%>%
   summarise(mode_weekday = max(n()))

july_data%>%
   group_by(weekday)%>%
   summarise(mode_weekday = max(count(weekday)))

july_data%>%
   group_by(weekday)%>%
   summarise(mode_weekday = max(table(weekday)))
```